# jQuery .load - Only display when all functions are complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently loading products onto my page via .load from a gallery page which containes several more products.

Once these products (first 3) have loaded in, I then get the href that was loaded in and then .load again to get product specific information from the product page.

**STEP ONE:**

```
EMPTY DIV                           EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV                           EMPTY DIV
EMPTY DIV                           EMPTY DIV
```

**STEP TWO:**

```
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     EMPTY DIV
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     EMPTY DIV
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     EMPTY DIV
```

**STEP THREE:**

```
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     PRODUCT INFORMATION FROM PRODUCTSPECIFIC URL
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     PRODUCT INFORMATION FROM PRODUCTSPECIFIC URL
LOADED PRODUCT ANCHOR AND IMAGE     PRODUCT INFORMATION FROM PRODUCTSPECIFIC URL
```

**This is what I have and it works exactly how I want it to:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.prdContainer .prdHero').each(function(i){

        var $parent = $(this).closest('.prdContainer');

        $(this).load(('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productMainImage'), function(){

            var prdLink = $parent.find('.prdHero .productMainImage').attr('href');

            $parent.find('.prdDesc').each(function(){
                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '.productHeading, .productReviews, .productWasPrice, .productNowPrice, .productSavePrice'); //.pluck-review-rollup-output-line
            });

            $parent.find('#prdDetails').each(function(){
                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '#productDescription');
                $('.prdDetails').show();
            });

        });
    });
});
```

**BUT!!!**

It loads in and displays content as soon as it gets it.  I want EVERYTHING to continue to load until the last thing has loaded and display it all at once, rather than it load in and display one by one.

Does anybody have any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: add a display none on your initial container and on the final load operation do a display block

Comment: I was about to explain how to use the `.when()` function till I realized you were re-writing the DOM with `.load()` causing a series of events each with DOM changes. This is something I would never do. I would instead use `.get()` and use the JSON data to write the HTML in JavaScript instead of the server. Because of the difference in design choices I redacted my original answer but wanted to comment to offer a different perspective for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to count executed load calls and when it reachs to zero show the container:

```
$(function(){
    $('.prdContainer').hide();
    var loadCallsCount = $('.prdContainer .prdHero').length * 2;

    $('.prdContainer .prdHero').each(function(i){

        var $parent = $(this).closest('.prdContainer');

        $(this).load(('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productMainImage'), function(){

            var prdLink = $parent.find('.prdHero .productMainImage').attr('href');

            $parent.find('.prdDesc').each(function(){
                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '.productHeading, .productReviews, .productWasPrice, .productNowPrice, .productSavePrice', function() {
                    loadCallsCount -= 1;
                    if (loadCallsCount == 0) $('.prdContainer').show();
                }); //.pluck-review-rollup-output-line
            });

            $parent.find('#prdDetails').each(function(){
                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '#productDescription', function() {
                    loadCallsCount -= 1;
                    if (loadCallsCount == 0) $('.prdContainer').show();
                });
                $('.prdDetails').show();
            });

        });
    });
});
```